# MySQL start and stop time of a device

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with trending data, the structure is like this:

```
[Timestamp, System_State]
2012-01-01 00:00:00, 1
2012-01-01 00:01:00, 1
2012-01-01 00:02:00, 0
2012-01-01 00:03:00, 1
2012-01-01 00:04:00, 1
2012-01-01 00:05:00, 0
...
```

Now I need to write a SQL query to know when the system starts (system_state changes from 0 to 1) and when it stops (state changes from 1 to 0). Do I have any options beside using cursor?

Thanks.

Comment: Finding those edges is not difficult. But unless you clearly describe your intended result / requirement, it's tough to offer a specific answer.  MySQL does not support window functions.  This would be the normal approach.  There are methods that can be used for some of the more basic window operations with primitive SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this (this is T-SQL, i.e. SQL Server, but may be applicable to MySql too)

```
declare @t table (eventTime datetime, eventState bit)

insert @t select '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 1
union all select '2012-01-01 00:01:00', 1
union all select '2012-01-01 00:02:00', 0
union all select '2012-01-01 00:03:00', 1
union all select '2012-01-01 00:04:00', 1
union all select '2012-01-01 00:05:00', 0

select *
from
(
    select eventTime, eventState, row_number() over (order by eventTime, eventState)r 
    from @t
) a
inner join
(
    select eventTime, eventState, row_number() over (order by eventTime, eventState)r 
    from @t
) b
on a.r = b.r-1
where a.eventState <> b.eventState
```

--alteratively:

```
select *
from @t a
where exists (
    select 1
    from @t b
    where a.eventTime > b.eventTime
    and a.eventState != b.eventState
    and not exists
    (
        select 1
        from @t c
        where a.eventTime > c.eventTime
        and b.eventTime < c.eventTime
    )
)
order by eventTime
```

--or

```
select *
from @t a
inner join @t b
    on a.eventTime > b.eventTime
    and a.eventState != b.eventState
left outer join @t c
    on a.eventTime > c.eventTime
    and b.eventTime < c.eventTime
where c.eventState is null
order by a.eventTime
```

Comment: No worries; have I got the right end of the stick in terms of what your problem is; just my implementation didn't work on MySQL, or have I misunderstood what you're attempting to do?  In case it's the former, I've rewritten the SQL in a simpler way which is more likely to work on MySQL.